# Is it possible to parallelize awk writing to multiple files through GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, file, awk, io-redirection, gnu-parallel

I am running an awk script which I want to parallelize through GNU parallel.

This script demultiplexes one input file to multiple output files depending on a value on each line. The code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    # bc is the field that defines to which file the line
    # will be written
    bc = $1
    # append line to such file
    print >> (bc".txt")
}
```

I want to parallelize it using GNU parallel through the following:

```
parallel --line-buffer --block 1G --pipe 'awk script.awk'
```

However, I am afraid of possible race conditions in which two awk processes are writing in the same file at the same time. Is it possible, and if yes how to avoid it without compromising parallelization?

NB. I included `--line-buffer` option although I'm not sure if it applies also to file redirection within the awk script. Does it apply also in this case or only to stdout of each awk process?

#### Example

```
# Input file
bc1    line1
bc3    line2
bc1    line3
bc2    line4


# Output file bc1.txt
bc1    line1
bc1    line3

# Output file bc2.txt
bc2    line4

# Output file bc3.txt
bc3    line2
```

Comment: It's tricky to get rid of all buffering.  Safer to let each process write to a separate file and concatenate them afterwards.

Comment: I'll be surprised if this is possible.  But maybe you need to tell us why you think you need to parallelize this. Just let `awk` run thru once, and write as you show here. If you get more than `*N*` open files though, you'll have to close after each write. (where N is the number of open files allowed to a process by your OS). Good luck!

Comment: @karakfa the solution I'm testing right now is doing exactly this - but since it requires more operations I wanted to know if there was an out-of-box solution.

Comment: @shellter good point on the number of open files. I need to parallelize this since I have a very big file that I want to split into chunks since single-core awk is currently the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by demultiplexing the output in different dirs:

```
stuff |
  parallel --block 10M --pipe --round-robin \
    'mkdir -p dir-{%}; cd dir-{%}; awk ../script.awk'
```

Or if input is a file, you can use `--pipepart` which is faster:

```
parallel --block -1 --pipepart -a bigfile \
  'mkdir -p dir-{%}; cd dir-{%}; awk ../script.awk'
```

Then there is no race condition. Finish up by merging the dirs:

```
parallel 'cd {}; ls' ::: dir-* | sort -u |
  parallel 'cat */{} > {}'
```

If merging is not acceptable (maybe you do not have disk space for 2 copies of the data), you can use fifos. But to do that you need to know the names of all the `.txt`-files in advance and you need a system that can run one process per name in parallel (10000 names = 10000 processes):

```
# Generate names-of-files.txt somehow
# Make fifos for all names in all slots
parallel 'mkdir -p {2}; mkfifo {2}/{1}' :::: \
  names-of-files.txt <(seq $(parallel --number-of-threads) )
# Run the demultiplexer in the background
parallel --block -1 --pipepart -a bigfile \
  'mkdir -p dir-{%}; cd dir-{%}; awk ../script.awk' &
# Start one process per name
# If you have more than 32000 names, you will need to increase the number
# of processes on your system.
cat names-of-files.txt |
  parallel -j0 --pipe -N250 -I ,, parallel -j0 'parcat */{} > {}'
```

Comment: Thanks! Additional: if I want to split the file only on set of lines (I can interleave lines but each line should remain whole to be processed) should I use `--line-buffer` with `--pipepart`?

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean. But `--linebuffer` only makes sense if the output is from `parallel` - not from `awk`. Provide 3 examples of input and output.

Comment: I added the example to my OP. Let's say there are 3 jobs in parallel, I want each one to process 1 or more lines but only an integer number of lines (not parts of line - let's say line1 and part of line2). Hope this is clear.

Comment: That is what my solution does. Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, but I was confused by the concept of block size with pipepart - I thought that block size was fixed and the last record was only partially included. Now it is clear thanks.

Comment: `parallel .... | parallel ...` Some people have all the fun! ;-) . Good luck to all.